# Error linking plugins while statically compiling Qt 5.5

Tags: qt, build, compilation, qt5

I'm attempting to create a static build of Qt. I've configured as follows:

```
./configure -release -opensource -confirm-license -static -no-sql-sqlite -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-xcb -icu -openssl -nomake examples -skip xmlpatterns
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
g++ -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-O1 -fuse-ld=gold -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtdeclarative/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/lib -o ../../bin/qmltestrunner .obj/main.o .obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o   -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtdeclarative/lib -lQt5QuickTest -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/lib -lQt5Test -lQt5Widgets -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/plugins/platforms -lqxcb -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/xcb-static -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/plugins/xcbglintegrations -lqxcb-egl-integration -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/gl_integrations/xcb_egl/xcb-static -lqxcb-glx-integration -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/gl_integrations/xcb_glx/xcb-static -lQt5XcbQpa -lXi -lxcb-static -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtimageformats/plugins/imageformats -lqdds -lqicns -lqjp2 -lqmng -lqtga -lqtiff -lqwbmp -lqwebp -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/plugins/imageformats -lqico -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/plugins/egldeviceintegrations -lqeglfs-x11-integration -lX11-xcb -lxcb -lQt5EglDeviceIntegration -lQt5PlatformSupport -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lXrender -lXext -lX11 -ludev -lEGL -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtdeclarative/plugins/qmltooling -lqmldbg_qtquick2 -lQt5Quick -lQt5Gui -lqtharfbuzzng -lqmldbg_tcp -lQt5Qml -L/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/plugins/bearer -lqconnmanbearer -lqgenericbearer -lqnmbearer -lQt5Network -lQt5DBus -lQt5Core -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -lqtpcre -lm -ldl -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lGL -lpthread
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QXcbIntegrationPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QXcbEglIntegrationPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QXcbGlxIntegrationPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QDDSPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QICNSPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QJp2Plugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QMngPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QTgaPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QTiffPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QWbmpPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QWebpPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QICOPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QEglFSX11IntegrationPlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QConnmanEnginePlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QGenericEnginePlugin()'
.obj/qmltestrunner_plugin_import.o:qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_qmltestrunner_plugin_import.cpp: error: undefined reference to 'qt_static_plugin_QNetworkManagerEnginePlugin()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../../bin/qmltestrunner] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/coin/tmp/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtdeclarative/tools/qmltestrunner'
```

It seems to be an issue between plugins and static builds. The config does give the following warning:

> WARNING: Using static linking will disable the use of dynamically
>   loaded plugins. Make sure to import all needed static plugins,
>   or compile needed modules into the library.
>
> Qt is now configured for building. Just run 'make'.
>   Once everything is built, you must run 'make install'.
>   Qt will be installed into /usr/local/Qt-5.5.0
>
> Prior to reconfiguration, make sure you remove any leftovers from
>   the previous build.

However, it seems to indicate that it should work. What's the issue? Can I just disable these plugins or the tools that try to use them, since I don't think I will need them?

Comment: Try adding -nomake tests -opengl es2 Make sure to start clean or clean the configuration e.g. jom clean from the root and then configure again.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by AlexanderVX an unclean working directory AND an unclean rootfs directory, from a previous build and installation of the dynamic version of the SDK, was my problem.

I found that using the '-nomake tests' option during the configuration allowed the SDK build to complete but I then had the same linker errors when compiling my application against the SDK.

I traced my problem down to having both the static and dynamic link libraries (e.g. libqlinuxfb.a and libqlinuxfb.so) installed in the library directory of the rootfs. The linker then chose the dynamic version rather than the statically built version of the library and hence the 'qt_static_plugin*' symbols were not present. A clean of the build directory and the installed rootfs resolved the problem.

Comment: Hello Marcus2001, is it possible you could describe how to clean the build directory and install rootfs in details? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unclean working directory was the problem for me like AlexanderVX pointed out.

`git submodule foreach --recursive "git clean -dfx"`

is also possible for cleaning and a lot faster than

```
make/jom clean
```